# How can link with chrome:// get opened in firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

I have installed [REST client](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/restclient/) on firefox .

To my surprise when I launched this addon the address bar says `chrome://restclient/content/restclient.html`.

If I am not wrong `chrome://` means links or commands specific to chrome browser.

How is this possible ?

Comment: "If I am not wrong `chrome://` means chrome browser ." Oh how very wrong you are. Thanks a lot, Google.

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks for correcting me . That was not what I meant

Comment: @Let'sCode I added an example url to my answer

Comment: @Let's Code: You mean Google Chrome, right? Yeah, I'm telling you that's not what it means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The Chrome URL** is part of Mozilla's XUL, which stands for XML User Interface Language.

[xul](/questions/tagged/xul) can be used to write cross-platform applications such as Mozilla Firefox, where it is interpreted by the layout engine known as Gecko which renders Firefox's user interface and Web page display.

> **XUL files** can be referenced with a regular HTTP URL (or any type of URL) just like HTML files. The basic syntax of a chrome URL is as follows:
>
> `chrome://<package name>/<part>/<file.xul>`

Source: [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Tutorial/The_Chrome_URL)

Try this example: `chrome://browser/content/browser.xul`

Comment: It's worth emphasising that Mozilla's use of the name Chrome predates Google's use the same name for their browser.